# Encasing a filename inside an app.config file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config, filenames

Is it possible to encase filenames inside an app.config file and use them in your code?

For instance, this code works perfectly:

```
string folder = @"C:\CDR_FTP1\ttfiles_exported\";
```

If I want to get the above value from an app.config file

1. is it possible to do that?
2. what would the syntax be?

For instance, inside the app.config, I could try and have something like this:

```
<add key="InputDir" value=@"D:\CDR_FTP1\ttfiles_exported\" />
```

I can't add the "@" because it will give me the following error:

```
"The character '@', hexadecimla value 0x40 is illegal at the beginning of an XML name."
```

If I try and use it in my code like below, it's fine, but **where and how would I need to stick the "@" for the application to read it properly?**

```
string folder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["InputDir"];
```

Comment: Using the prefix `@` with a string in c# is called a `verbatim string literal`. It is useful when you want to avoid escaping characters like \ which show up many times in a file path. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for more information

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use:

```
<add key="InputDir" value="D:\CDR_FTP1\ttfiles_exported\" />
```

There is no need to escape `\` in XML attribute.

Comment: So, I don't need to do anything with the "@" in the code at all if I put the value in app.config --- correct?

Answer (score 9):

To expand Kirill's answer:

The special characters in XML attributes are different than those of C# strings.

In C# the character '\' is the string escape character, used to denote escape sequences such as '\n' for end of line, as you are probably aware; and hence needs to be escaped either as '\\' or by using @"".

In XML '\' has no especial meaning inside attribute values and can be use as is. This is not true for the '&' and '"' characters among others. If you wanted to include the value:

```
M & M "The chocolates"
```

in an app.config they would have to be escaped so:

```
<add key="SomeString" value="M &amp; M &quot;The chocolates&quot;" />
```